# Cannot import cross project in Nrwl Monorepo when using ts-node

Tags: typescript, monorepo, nrwl-nx, ts-node

I've setup a nrwl monorepo. All is working find. I have apps which import libraries, no issues. However, I've also created a `tools` library in which I can execute typescript files which perform tasks for me.

So, suppose I have only have two libraries

```
 ./libs/
        tools
        shared
```

Now Inside one of my tools I import shared

```
import { foo } from "@mono/shared";
```

Now, inside VSCODE I get already an error here:

```
Buildable libraries cannot import or export from non-buildable libraries
```

and when I try to execute my code I get

```
Error: Cannot find module '@mono/shared'
```

All my apps and libs are generated by `nx` cli, so everything looks fine. For example, in my `tsconfig.base.json` I see

```
paths: { "@mono/shared": ["./libs/shared/src/index.ts"] }
```

With `nx graph` I see the arrow going from `tools` to `shared`.

However, I have a custom command (project.json) to execute my tool:

```
"populate-db": {
  "executor": "nx:run-commands",
  "options": {
     "commands": ["ts-node  ./src/lib/populate-db.ts"],
     "cwd": "./libs/tools",
     "parallel": false
  }
}
```

My guess would be that this is the root cause of all my problems. Hope someone has an idea why this is not working!

Update: [this](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/2329) seems related and [Publishable and Buildable Nx Libraries](https://nx.dev/more-concepts/buildable-and-publishable-libraries)

UPDATE: When I convert my tools library into an app it all seems to work when I use the `tools:serve` command. Using a custom command with ts-node still has (different) issues